# Facebook thinks I stole the video i uploaded

Tags: facebook

I already tried 10+ but nothing happened but just the same always saying that this is copyright and a stolen video. But it was a video that has music and pictures for my project and I really need to post this video. How do I post this?

Comment: What does this have to do with RSS, which is the tag you used?

Answer (score 4):

If the images making up your video are guaranteed to be unique and not part of another video, then it is probably the music you used.  Frequently, online video hosting providers have to deal with copyright takedown notices, and if the song(s) you chose are on their list of regularly contested songs, then they will block them before upload, rather than deal with taking them down after a complaint by the owner.

You might try posting the video somewhere else (such as YouTube, Vimeo, or Flickr) and then sharing its location on Facebook.  However, if it contains songs that Facebook blocks, then it has a high chance of being blocked on those sites as well.

Another possible option would be to store the video in a shared folder on a site such as Dropbox or Copy.com.  This wouldn't necessarily let you stream the video, but the people you want to see it could download it and watch it from their own computers.